# How to remove black background on UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I want to create the TabBar which align at center no matter what how many tabitem is.

The final result may be look like the image below.

[image]

I can set width of TabBar by using

```
    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    CGRect rectAdjust = CGRectMake(tabBar.frame.origin.x, tabBar.frame.origin.y,  160.0f, tabBar.frame.size.height);
    tabBar.frame = rectAdjust;
```

But I cannot remove the black background on UITabBar(on the right side in below image) even though I already set the size of TabBar to be half the screen's width.

[image]

Is there any way to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Using a `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you could take a look at this control at the CocoaControls website:

[ALTabBarController for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/altabbarcontroller)

It is more customizable than the traditional TabBar

Answer (score 0):

You could set an image for the table bar that has caps on either side and a few pixels in between, then make it a resizeable image like so:

```
UIImage *background = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Then set it as the background image of the tab bar:

```
tabBar.backgroundImage = background;
```

And it should resize to the image you need.

Then set the background color of the tab bar to clear:

```
tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: Not sure why this is down voted, its actually a correct answer